# Building with Webpack3.6.0 , polymer webcomponents and Angular 4 fails

Tags: angular, webpack, polymer

I am using webpack 3.6 along with polymer-webpack-loader on an Angular 4 application.

```
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            use:['raw-loader','polymer-webpack-loader']
        }
```

This creates invalid html as seen in [image: polymer-webpack-loader & raw-loader]

However if i remove the polymer-webpack-load [image: No polymer plugin]
Note - The cd in this html is irritating but the code works as expected.

Any pointers might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Adding the include portion to restrict it to the components directory resolved the valid html portion at the index.html level. However the components are still not getting converted correctly.

[image: As seen on browser]